# Having trouble getting cake bake to work

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-bake

I've installed the latest version of CakePHP on a Ubuntu 10.10 machine. I was able to run through a beginner tutorial just fine so I think my configuration is close to being correct. I can't get cake bake to completely work though. Below is my session. Things that look like anomolies are in bold. I think I must have one or more small errors in my configuration that are manifesting when running the bake shell. Thanks!

ubuntu@myserver.com:~$ cd /var/www/app
ubuntu@myserver.com:/var/www/app$ ../cake/console/cake bake -app /var/www/app
**Failed loading /usr/lib/php5/20090626.so:  /usr/lib/php5/20090626.so: cannot open shared object**

file: No such file or directory

Welcome to CakePHP v1.3.2 Console

App : app
Path: /var/www/app

Interactive Bake Shell

[D]atabase Configuration
[M]odel
[V]iew
[C]ontroller
[P]roject
[F]ixture
[T]est case
[Q]uit
What would you like to Bake? (D/M/V/C/P/F/T/Q)

> P
>   What is the full path for this app including the app directory name?
>    Example:/var/www/app/myapp
>   [/var/www/app/myapp] > /var/www/app
>   Bake Project
>   Skel Directory: /usr/share/php/cake/console/templates/skel
>   Will be copied to: /var/www/app

Look okay? (y/n/q)
[y] > y
Do you want verbose output? (y/n)
[n] > y

Created: app in /var/www/app

/usr/share/php/cake/console/templates/skel/app_controller.php copied to

/var/www/app/app_controller.php
/usr/share/php/cake/console/templates/skel/app_model.php copied to
/var/www/app/app_model.php
/usr/share/php/cake/console/templates/skel/index.php copied to /var/www/app/index.php
/usr/share/php/cake/console/templates/skel/.htaccess copied to /var/www/app/.htaccess
/usr/share/php/cake/console/templates/skel/app_helper.php copied to   /var/www/app/app_helper.php

Creating file /var/www/app/views/pages/home.ctp
File `/var/www/app/views/pages/home.ctp` exists, overwrite? (y/n/q)
[n] > y
Wrote `/var/www/app/views/pages/home.ctp`
Welcome page created
Random hash key created for 'Security.salt'
Random seed created for 'Security.cipherSeed'
**Unable to set CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH, you should change it in   /var/www/app/webroot/index.php

Could not set permissions on /var/www/app//tmp

chmod -R 0777 /var/www/app//tmp**

Interactive Bake Shell

[D]atabase Configuration
[M]odel
[V]iew
[C]ontroller
[P]roject
[F]ixture
[T]est case
[Q]uit

What would you like to Bake? (D/M/V/C/P/F/T/Q)

> q
>   ubuntu@myserver.com:/var/www/app$

Comment: I guess it comes down to set the the include path right, then the php cli error could vanish. Seems that cake tries to load *.so from this folder, but as there is an additional slash it is "too high" in the folder tree. Just a rough guess...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mark Murphy,

1.

```
Failed loading /usr/lib/php5/20090626.so: /usr/lib/php5/20090626.so: cannot open shared object
```

*.so files are shared libraries. I would try to tackle it be (re-) installing the PHP CLI.

2.

```
Could not set permissions on /var/www/app//tmp
```

How could the slash creep in twice? Such a folder should not exist.

**Edit0:**
It is a bit strange, as CakePHP should work right out of the box, but maybe you really should take a look at the specified variable in app/webroot/index.php and see if you can change the CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH so that the superfluous slash vanishes.

**Edit1:**
For general deployment there is nothing better than [this](http://ad7six.com/2007/08/24/Production-setup-revisited.html) afaik.

**Edit2:**
`cake bake help` returns:
-app  Absolute/Relative path to your app folder.

Hence you should call either:

1. `cake bake app /var/www/<your_project_name>/   <---- note the trailing slash`
   or
2. when in `/var/www/` call `cake bake app <just_your_project_name>`

**Edit3:**
In a nutshell: You could download the CakePHP tar.gz and unzip it in your `/var/www/`, then rename the folder (having some weird `cakePHP-1234`... name) into the name of your application, e.g. `missioncontrol`. Then in your browser: `http://localhost/missioncontrol` , proceed as instructed.
This is a very quick method to get going, but you can develop other methods according to your build process.

After you have developed your app and intend to deploy it on a host different than your local machine, use the link provided under edit1.

Comment: Thanks Benjamin, I tried reinstalling php5-cli. Same result. ../cake/console/cake is trying to load 20090626.so. This .so does not exist. 20090626 is a directory of shared objects though. I've searched for places I might have misconfigured cake. No idea why on /var/www/app//tmp...

Comment: The suggestion in edit2 kind of worked. However, cake bake insisted on putting the app at /var/www/app/app. This had the effect of making the process work though. It makes me wonder if I should have installed cakephp at /var/www/cakephp rather than at my web root. What's the typical practice?